# Spring MVC + maven как прочитать .properties из корня приложения

Tags: spring-mvc, maven

Здравствуйте, я недавно уже задавал немного похожий вопрос, но оказалось, что то было не совсем то, что мне нужно.

У меня проект spring mvc + maven.  Проект читает параметры из файла `src\main\resources\application.properties`.
После деплоя на Glassfish, этот файл оказывается тут: `glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\AppName\WEB-INF\classes\application.properties`

В самом Sping MVC файл подгружается таким способом :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

Мне нужно, исключить `.properties`, из war'ника, и чтобы задеплоенный проект искал их тут: `glassfish\domains\domain1\config` (как если бы это происходило, если бы это был не maven проект).

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как я могу это сделать.

Comment: а что вы хотите этим добиться?

Comment: такое требование, чтобы .properties файл читался не из glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\AppName\WEB-INF\classes\application.properties  куда он попадает из .war архива.
а читался из  glassfish\domains\domain1\config